# Make custom UITextView selection bar with only translate in Swift 5

Tags: swift, uitextview, translation

Is there a way to only allow the new translate option of ios15 in a custom UITextView? See the following picture to know what I mean with translate option:

[Translate option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvy5C.jpg)

I know about the canPerformAction method but there is no translate option:

```
class CustomUITextField: UITextField {
   override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible. The API is private. You can remove all the actions available via UIResponder, or create your own menu with a custom button and connect it to your own translate API

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Please be aware that the translate option relies on a private API and therefore should be used with caution.**

As for achieving the desired result, you can use the following code snippet in Swift:

```swift
action == Selector(stringLiteral: "_translate:")
```